# Apache Flink Stateful Functions state scaling

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

We are able to scale stateless functions as much as we want. But stateful functions likely to be bottleneck if we don't scale them as we scale stateless functions. Scaling state seems to be tricky because of the distribution of the data across the nodes. If stateful functions become a bottlenecks, can we scale them too?

Answer (score 0):

Stateful functions are scaled exactly in the same way as stateless.

In **StateFun**, the remote functions are in fact stateless processes that receive the state just prior to the invocation for a given key, and after a successful invocation the changes to the state are communicated back to the Flink cluster. Therefore scaling stateless or stateful functions is really the same.

To learn more I'd recommend watching [a keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NF0hXZfUyqE&t=21s) introducing **StateFun** 2.0 or visiting the [distributed architecture page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-2.0/concepts/distributed_architecture.html)